Failed to resolve: com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.5
I am getting filepicker dependency error in my android app. It is not able to resolve the dependency version. I am using the version 2.2.5 as mentioned in the documentation.
I tried to download it manually but am unable to find jar file on web. It is written that target SDK version should be 29, I also tried that but same sync issues persist. Also, its older versions like 2.0.3 and 2.1.5 are not working.
